# Ubercart - Attempt to e-mail invoice for order 14 to failed

Tags: email, drupal, ubercart, paypal-ipn

Ubercart is failing to send invoice when it receives a payment from IPN. The error I get is:

'Attempt to e-mail invoice for order 14 to failed'

The only thing I can think of is that it's not running as admin so doesn't have privileges to send the message.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in `ubercart/uc_order/uc_order.ca.inc`

```
  foreach ($recipients as $email) {
    $sent = drupal_mail('uc_order', 'action-mail', $email, uc_store_mail_recipient_language($email), $settings, empty($settings['from']) ? uc_store_email_from() : $settings['from']);

    if (!$sent['result']) {
      watchdog('ca', 'Attempt to e-mail invoice for order @order_id to @email failed.', array('@email' => $email, '@order_id' => $order->order_id), WATCHDOG_ERROR);
    }
  }
```

Ubercart only use default drupal_mail to sent mail.
Are you sure your server is able to sent mails ?

To be sure this is working, you could try to use the function "Retrieve lost password" that also send emails.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. The Retrieve Password functionality works perfectly though.

Comment: So you definitely need to do some debugging around there. Use the [watchdog](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/6) function to log what you have in $email, inside the foreach. Something like `watchdog('debug', print_r($email, 1));`

Answer (score 1):

Check the Watchdog log (Admin > Reports > Recent log entries) to see if there is any more detail. The Drupal handbooks have a page on [troubleshooting email](http://drupal.org/node/475054).

Answer (score 0):

I've just solve the problem!

For 99% you didn't setup your store emial adress under..

> [your site] > ADMINISTER > STORE ADMINISTRATION > CONFIGURATION >
>   CONTACT SETTINGS > Store settings

or link

> admin/store/settings/store/edit/contact

Check this comment http://www.ubercart.org/forum/support/10816/unable_send_email#comment-39056

Comment: another problem is the blank line in recipient textarea. so remove any blank line as drupal will consider this blank line as an item!